# Get the first fully visible view

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to know if the first view is fully visible.

This code return 0, even if a small portion of the cell 0 is visible (0 is an example, it could by X).

```
mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()
```

Is there any method available or calcul for my problem ?

Comment: do u try `listView.getChildAt(0)`?

Comment: Hum, getChildAt(0) get the first item. This is not my question..

Comment: first visible ListView item is from this, so can you able to do some trick with this ??

Comment: I think you don't understand my problem. I want to get the visible FULLY visible item. Not the first visible item. This is two things really differents.